# How can you do a persistent search using the Apache 2.0.1 LDAP API in JAVA

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

I am wondering if there is a way to connect to ldap (389 server) through the apache 2.0.1 java ldap api and then continuously listen for changes to a specific attribute on a set of entries (in this case people with specific qualifications)?

Ideally I would like to run a query on ou=people,dc=test,dc=local
this might initially return
dn: uid=tester1,ou=people,dc=test,dc=local
givenName: tester1

dn: uid=tester2,ou=people,dc=test,dc=local
givenName: tester2

dn: uid=tester3,ou=people,dc=test,dc=local
givenName: tester3

If I then in the background changed tester3's givenName to userTester3 I would like to have a listener that would return some userModified event telling me that tester3 was modified.

**As an example of what I would like to happen (psuedo code / non functioning code) I would like to do something along the lines of :**

```
{
 PersistentSearch ps = new PersistentSearch();
 ps.setChangeType(ChangeType.MODIFY);
 SearchRequest sr = ldaputility.createPersistentSearch(qualifiers, attributes, etc, ps);
 PersistentSearchListener psl = new PersistentSearchListener(sr){
   @Override
   public void entryChanged(Entry e){
     Log.info("The entry just changed");
  }
 }
}
```

There however from what I can tell in the apache 2.0.1 api **is not any persistent search listener nor is there any type of listener for search requests in general** and the search request gets results and then completes.  I know that in the netscape api there is a search listener and that in the apache directory server api there is a persistent search listener. So what I am asking is does anyone know if the **apache 2.0.1 ldap api** supports a behavior where you make an initial query and any time the results of the query change you can have a listener that is notified of the new changes?

I unfortunately have no debugging code / output since I am not even sure what code to try right now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by adding a PersistentSearch control (with changes only set to true and change types set to modifications) to the search request the ldap server won't ever set isDone to true on the search request so then the search request will continue to return the updates as they are available.